# Typescript compiler error property does not exist on object

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm receiving typescript errors 'property does not exist on object' from my typescript files. I've read a few posts regarding this but I'm still unsure how to implement the work around.

I have a JSON object has two properties, I unpack it so I can access both of the values directly, which works fine, it's just a compile time I receive the error.

```
payload: {
   value1: '',
   value2: ''
}
```

my private method is where the issues are coming through.

```
private update(respo : Object) : void {

    if (respo.hasOwnProperty('value1') || respo.hasOwnProperty('value2')) {
        (<FormControl>this.controlGroup.controls['ctrlone']).setValue(respo.value1);

        (<FormControl>this.controlGroup.controls['ctrltwo']).setValue(respo.value2);
    }
}
```

I tried to export an interface like the one below but I get a console error '? parameter not found'

```
 interface responseObject {
    value1?: string
    value2?: string
 }
```

Any help is appreciated. I'm using typescript 1.8.

Jimi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue appears to be with the type argument. Don't type that as `Object`. Though I'm not sure what the issue is with your interface (it might be that you are missing semicolons?)

This works for me:

```
interface responseObject {
    value1?: string;
    value2?: string;
}

class SomeClass {
    private update(respo : responseObject) : void {
        if (respo.hasOwnProperty('value1') || respo.hasOwnProperty('value2')) {
            (<FormControl>this.controlGroup.controls['ctrlone']).setValue(respo.value1);

            (<FormControl>this.controlGroup.controls['ctrltwo']).setValue(respo.value2);
        }
    }
}
```

When you type something as `Object` the only attributes that the compiler knows about are those that exist on [Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object). Making an interface is definitely the *correct* way to go about this (so good on you for that!) but in the future, the "workaround" you are probably looking for is type `any`.